# Can't Instantiate Field (instance variable) in main() method. Why?? Java

Tags: java, variables, exception, field, program-entry-point

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? When I have this code in Eclipse, it is telling me I cannot "make a static reference to a non-static field" when I try to set `sheetName` to `"hi"` in the main method. What am I doing wrong here? I know it must be simple, but I searched everywhere and cannot figure it out!

```
public class AutoExpire {

private String sheetName;
private FileInputStream inputStream;

/**
 * Instantiates the class.
 */
public AutoExpire() {
    // do nothing
}

/**
 * The main method from which the program is ran.
 * 
 * @param args
 *            No arguments.
 * @throws IOException
 *             If program fails to run.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    sheetName = "hi";
```

Comment: `static` means it is part of the class, not so much of a class instance (the object itself). Non-static fields such as sheetName are however part of instances of the class. Normally you would create the class using a constructor that has a string argument and assign the field from the constructor. If the class can live without the `sheetName`, you could also create a setter. But whatever you do you should set the field during or after creating the class instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `main` method is static, so you have no instances of `AutoExpire` in the `main` method.  Create an instance, then set the instance's field.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    AutoExpire ae = new AutoExpire();
    ae.sheetName = "hi";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response! Can you look at the comment bellow and possibly answer it on this (your) comment thread? Thanks again!