# wordArray cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, arrays

I have a code which focuses on converting a sentence into a String array using a .split() method. Everything is running smooth up until I want to print it out using a for loop.

I have declared a wordArray Array, but when I try to run my main, it just doesn't seem to be a able to tie it together.

```
public class WordGroup{
    private String words;
    private String[] wordArray = words.split(" ");

    public WordGroup(String newWords) {
        words = newWords.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String[] getWordArray() {
        return wordArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordGroup WordGroup1 = new WordGroup("You can discover more about a person in an hour of play than in a year of conversation");
        WordGroup WordGroup2 = new WordGroup("When you play play hard when you work dont play at all");

        WordGroup1.getWordArray();
        WordGroup2.getWordArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(wordArray[i] + " ");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WordGroup1.getWordArray()` or `WordGroup2.getWordArray()` will work

Comment: What is the Out-Value of your main-method?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181243/cant-instantiate-field-instance-variable-in-main-method-why-java

Comment: wordArray cannot be resolved to a variable
 wordArray cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: try to use for like this : for(String s:WordGroup1.getWordArray()){....}

Comment: Saulo, I did that, but then it gives me NullPointerException

Comment: Don't name your variables starting with uppercase, it hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that my getWordArray() method was wrong. I updated it to this:

```
public String[] getWordArray() {
    wordArray = words.split(" ");
    return wordArray;

}
```

and by using Saulo's advice (  for(String s:WordGroup1.getWordArray() ), it seems to be running just as intended. Thank you, for your help.